# LG G2 (Android 4.2.2) not recognized by Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, driver

I've installed Eclipse, the Android SDK and enabled the developer mode on my phone. When I plug it, I can choose the kind of connection I want and I choose the Internet connection. Everything looks good regarding the drivers (the ADB driver installer says so) but Eclipse does not recognize my phone. How can I manage this issue to make my phone detected by Eclipse?

Comment: Did you try stopping (adb kill-server) and re-starting (adb start-server) the adb server

Comment: Yes indeed I've seen a lot of command like the ones you've posted but I have no idea where I can type them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I was having the same issue.  I solved it by:

1. Setting connection mode to Internet Connection (Ethernet)
2. Unplugging and plugging my phone into my computer.
3. Running the LG software that comes up as an autorun option to install the drivers.

After that, adb/eclipse had no trouble seeing my device.